# Visualforce Canvas App not getting signed request

Tags: visualforce, canvas

I have a connected app, with canvas component in a visualforce page using `<apex:canvasApp>`. Signed Request (POST) is enabled.

If I admin-approve users, the canvas app gets a valid Signed Request POSTed with auth_token and refresh_token, like expected.

The problem occurs if I choose user self-authorization:
I initiate the OAuth flow using `Sfdc.canvas.oauth.login`and on the Callback URL, I use `window.opener.Sfdc.canvas.oauth.childWindowUnloadNotification(window.location.hash)` to emit the result to the canvas.

This reloads the canvas page and I can then access the auth_token using `Sfdc.canvas.oauth.token()`

However, a call to `Sfdc.canvas.client.refreshSignedRequest` leads to a respone `Code 403 "userApprovalRequired"` with empty payload.

I can see in the background a http request made to `https://eu3.salesforce.com/services/data/v36.0/platformconnect/signedrequest`, returning an encoded response. If I decode it using my client secret, it gives me a CanvasRequest with issuedAt = NULL and no auth_token or refresh_token

Also, calling `Sfdc.canvas.client.repost({refresh : true})` does not lead to a POST on my canvas page, but again a GET request with `_sfdc_canvas_authvalue = user_approval_required`

Am I missing a step or doeing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just solved the problem.

You need to initialize a Web Server OAuth Authentication Flow using

```
response_type : 'code'
```

and complete fetching the tokens on the server. After you complete the oauth flow you can call the repost() function on the canvas page and you will get the signed request.

A User-Agent OAuth Authentication Flow is not good enough it seems.